# SQL retrieve inner query value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following query:

```
select SUM(balvalues) from
(
    select ib.CURBAL as balvalues from invbalances ib join inventory on ib.itemnum = inventory.itemnum and ib.location = inventory.location where inventory.itemnum = 'XMP-3500' and ib.siteid = 'BEDFORD'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT -1 * SUM(QUANTITY) from matrectrans where itemnum = 'XMP-3500' and TRANSDATE >= '16-SEP-99' and tostoreloc = 'CENTRAL'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT -1 * SUM(QUANTITY) from matusetrans where itemnum = 'XMP-3500' and TRANSDATE >= '16-SEP-99' and storeloc = 'CENTRAL'
);
```

However I want to add another column in the outer `select (itemnum)` so I can `join` with another query:

```
select SUM(balvalues), ib.itemnum
```

I've tried adding the itemnum to each of the inner selects to make sure I have the same number of output columns for all `unions` and the outer but I still got this error:

> ORA-00904: "IB"."ITEMNUM": invalid identifier

How can I get the itemnum value from the subquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add itemnum to your inner and outer queries. Add group-bys to your inner queries and to the outer query.

```
select SUM(balvalues), itemnum from
(
    select ib.CURBAL as balvalues, inventory.itemnum as itemnum from invbalances ib join inventory on ib.itemnum = inventory.itemnum and ib.location = inventory.location where inventory.itemnum = 'XMP-3500' and ib.siteid = 'BEDFORD'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT -1 * SUM(QUANTITY), itemnum from matrectrans where itemnum = 'XMP-3500' and TRANSDATE >= '16-SEP-99' and tostoreloc = 'CENTRAL' group by itemnum
    UNION ALL
    SELECT -1 * SUM(QUANTITY), itemnum from matusetrans where itemnum = 'XMP-3500' and TRANSDATE >= '16-SEP-99' and storeloc = 'CENTRAL' group by itemnum
) group by itemnum;
```

Comment: I tried the query and added a group by to all the inner queries but I'm getting this error:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: Try changing the inner query to `SELECT SUM(-1*QUANTITY) as balvalues, itemnum...`

Comment: It worked now. I had to add the group by statement at the end of the expression as well:

select SUM(balvalues), itemnum from (...) group by itemnum;

Comment: Edited answer - added the missing group by.

Answer (score 0):

The outer select do not know this column
You need also to add it in all the inners select

Comment: I did that and now I get this error:
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: Did you add group by in your SQL?

Comment: So you put groupby as i suspected and now it works after removing it.